# How can i make zip folder of all the files selected from Document Library in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, multi-select

I want to make the zip folder of all the selected files from document library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Their is no such OOTB functionality available for it. But their are couple 3rd party products available which give you this options.

1. [SharePoint Bulk Zip & Unzip](http://www.boostsolutions.com/sharepoint-bulk-zip-unzip.html)
2. [Download multiple documents for SharePoint 2010](http://www.sharepointanalysthq.com/2012/10/download-multiple-documents-for-sharepoint-2010/)
3. may write some code...check this [Download files as Zip File in SharePoint](http://adicodes.com/download-files-as-zip-file-in-sharepoint/)

I would also try to open document library in explorer and then try to zip it fromt heir

Answer (score 0):

There is also this solution, which does the same thing that you ask for.

I've used this before, and it works fine.

http://www.amrein.com/apps/page.asp?Q=5826

Free trial available.

I've also just found this one, which I am going to check out myself:

http://kb.winzip.com/help/help_express4sp.htm