# Download Search Results

Tags: search-results

I have a search page that allows users to search for documents refined by certain metadata properties.  The documents are scattered across multiple libraries in multiple site collections, but have the same content type.  Is there a way to download the documents from the search results?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a custom anchor tag in the Item Template of the search results and for each document set the URL of anchor tag to

```
http://spsite/_layouts/download.aspx?SourceUrl=http://spsite/Documents/sample.docx
```

This will download the file from the SharePoint directly.

Source [LINK](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/47729/link-to-download-a-copy-from-a-document-library)

Comment: have you seen a technique to download multiple items at one time? For example add a checkbox to the display template and then select an download them all as a zip file?

Comment: @MatthewMcDermott: I dont think there is any OOTB feature available for it..you need to iterate through all the documents and then write some custom logic to download them in a zip file.. this link might be helpful for you.
https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/120729/how-can-i-make-zip-folder-of-all-the-files-selected-from-document-library-in-sha

Comment: Thanks Ankit for your answer.  I apologize my requirements were not clear.  I was looking for a bulk download solution similar to what Matthew McDermott has described.  We are currently looking at 3rd party tools as well.  So far we have found list rollup tools and bulk download tools but they don't work together.

Comment: Hi all, i am also looking for multiple download of sharepoint online search results. Please provide the way if you find it... thank you